# Mysql DISTINCT not working in my language properly

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin, distinct

I have a problem with DISTINCT in SQL select. I have table with following values in column:

```
sítotisk
sitotisk
```

when I use DISTINCT - so the result is only "sítotisk" ...db system think, that is the same word, but i need the words have seperaly.

Comment: show us the database table and the query that you are using

Comment: please elaborate your question and post your code, what you have to tired ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a collation problem. I guess you're using an accent insensitive collation. You can check that in your server/DB/table properties.

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT yourColumn COLLATE utf8_bin
FROM ...
```

You might want to take a look at these questions that address the same issue:

- [How to conduct an Accent Sensitive search in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500826/1679537)
- [How to MySQL work “case insensitive” and “accent insensitive” in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10831076/1679537)

Comment: Thank you for lead - the right collate was COLLATE utf8_bin

Comment: Yes, I was confused at first with sql server collations :)